# Using both postgresql and mysql in Rails 3?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My database adapter that Rails uses in production is PostgreSQL, but I need to query a MySQL database on another server. I've included the 'mysql2' gem in my Gemfile and bundle install ran fine.

In my application controller I have `client = Mysql2::Client.new(...)`, but I get uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Mysql2.

Why isn't bundler loading the mysql2 gem? I tried putting `require 'mysql2'` in application controller but get a file not found.

Note I'm using ruby 1.9.3p125 and rails 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Call [`establish_connection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-establish_connection) on the model that represents the data which is in a secondary database. Rails should figure it out.

```
Data.establish_connection adapter: 'mysql'  # ...
```

The hash that must be passed is similar to the ones in your database configuration files. Check the documentation for an example.

Comment: I don't need to create a model for this data, I simple need to query the database for info. I shouldn't have to involve Active Record at all. Isn't there a way to just establish a connection with another database?

Comment: @Brian, I suppose you can use the adapter directly, but you've already tried that. I'm not sure what's wrong with your approach, and unfortunately I can't it test right now.

Comment: @Brian, did you add `gem 'mysql2'` to your `Gemfile`? Bundler will load _only_ the gems you've specified there, no matter what you have installed.

Comment: Mat, yes I have done that unfortunately =/. It's included with every environment the app runs in.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. However, assuming that it is possible to just:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(...)
```

...from within the rails app, and a connection can be made successfully (try it in console first). Then, I would put the mysql connection into a class in the /lib dir of your Rails app, and then:

```
require 'yourlib'
```

..in the top of your controller. Then you can use your class and methods in the controller.

The lib file you create, and the code you write to use the lib file  can also be tested in rails console, too.